# REST api return diferent data type with retrofit

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

I'm using a REST api with retrofit2 and i have

> http://myApi:3000/user/{user_id}/messages

On this route the api can return either a list of message or a single message

```
#If multiple message the api response is 
[
   { 
     id: 1,
     message: "message1"
   },
   { 
     id: 2,
     message: "message2"
   }
]

#Else if there is only one message
{ 
  id: 4,
  message: "message4"
}
```

For now I have

```
public interface MessageRequest {
    @GET("/user/{user_id}/messages")
    Call<List<Message>> tour(@Path("user_id") long user_id);
}
```

But this only work in the case that there is many message in the case that there is only one i get this exception

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Is there a way to convert my result in a Array of only on message ?

Hope that I'm specific enough, please ask me for any more precision if needed.

Comment: Return array of 1 element when has only one message

Comment: Or override gson deserialize method